# How to browse an query id not follow PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, matching

I need your help about an modification of my actual code. Here it is :

```
\timing on
DO $$
BEGIN
    DECLARE
        i INT := 1; -- valeur de départ à changer pour la range d'id
        j INT := i + 1;
        numberUsers INT; -- Changer valeur numberUsers pour fin de la range d'id
        commonSkills INT;
        random INT;
        idSphere INT := 2;
    BEGIN
        SELECT COUNT(*) INTO numberUsers FROM "WU_Users"; -- si numberUSers est modifié, commentez la ligne
        WHILE i < numberUsers LOOP
            WHILE j <= numberUsers LOOP
                IF i !=j THEN
                    SELECT floor(random() * 10 + 35)::INT INTO random;
                    INSERT INTO "WU_MatchingUsers"("IDWU_User1", "IDWU_User2", "MatchingScore")
                        VALUES(i, j, random)
                            ON CONFLICT ("id") 
                                DO
                                    UPDATE SET "MatchingScore" = EXCLUDED."MatchingScore";
                ELSE
                    RAISE NOTICE 'Same Users';
                END IF;
                j := j + 1;
            END LOOP;
        j := i + 1;
        RAISE NOTICE 'i: %', i;
        i := i + 1; 
        END LOOP;
    END;
END $$;
\timing off
```

So this code take two id, and with two loops "browse" from i to numberUsers and insert into another table a random matching score, now I need to add this :

```
SELECT "IDWU_Users_WU_Users" FROM "WU_UsersSpheres" WHERE "IDWU_UsersSpheres" = idSphere;
```

This line return me a list of id from another table that I need to match, like the script above I match in this order :

```
1/2
1/3
```

etc etc

But now this new line can return me id like that :

```
532
1426
3236
84697
```

And I need to make the same matching system than before so like that :

```
532/1426
532/3236
532/84697
```

Kind Regards !

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want to accomplish.  I doubt a `while` loop is needed for this.

Comment: What you mean ? I thinked I explained all what was needed, like, I said I just have id number : 1,2,3 that I already succeed to match, I now need to make the same process for Id that not follow like : 1,5,12 etc

Comment: He means in order to make it easier to help you it is beneficial to provide definitions of the tables and sample data, please have a read of a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)